# Ошибка в модуле pyowm

Tags: pyowm

```
owm = OWM('70dc8c4ff27f3e79f9c49da91dc517f3')
place = input('Укажите город: ')
mgr = owm.weather_manager()
observation = mgr.weather_at_place(place)
w = observation.weather
print('В городе' + place + 'сейчас' + (w.detailed_status())
print(w)
```

Выводит ошибку **TypeError: 'str' object is not callable**
Думаю, окей, если жалуется на Integer, тогда этот код надо превратить на вид данных String (str)
Так вот.

```
owm = OWM('70dc8c4ff27f3e79f9c49da91dc517f3')
place = input('Укажите город: ')
mgr = owm.weather_manager()
observation = mgr.weather_at_place(place)
w = observation.weather
print('В городе' + place + 'сейчас' + str(w.detailed_status()))
print(w)
```

И пишет тоже самое **TypeError: 'str' object is not callable**
По идее, я превратил код в вид данных
Пожалуйста, помогите исправить эту ошибку. Я буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Напишите вместо `w.detailed_status()` вот так:`w.detailed_status`

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Не за что, обращайтесь)